# Run python Pytest testcases from jenkins with git

Tags: python, jenkins, junit, pytest, cicd

I have a github repo where few pytest testcases are there. I want to clone and run these testcases using jenkins and then publish a junit report. I am able to successfully clone the repo but how can i run the pytest testcase present in the repo and publish a junit report.
My jenkins configureation include:

1. custom python builder

   pytest-3 --junitxml testresult.xml
2. publish junit report

   *.xml

3- my jenkins location

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<<allprojects>>
```

I see the following error

> ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report
> files were found. Configuration error? Finished: FAILURE

Also see the below picture for reference!
[image]

Comment: Did the tests run?

Comment: @DevangSanghani no i guess,
then later i wrote command to run test in bash-windows but the problem still there.

Comment: Also i am getting this error

Recording test results
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
Finished: FAILURE